# What does " rand()% 11" and what's the diffrence between this and "rand()% 10+1"?

Tags: c

I know that rand() generates a random number and that % operator returns the rest of the division but what I don't understand is why do we Have to use it here why can't we just give a max number directly like 10 for example

Answer (score 6):

The difference between `% 11` and `%10 +1` can be understood if you try a sample:

`%11` gives 11 possible answers: `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`

`%10 + 1` gives 10 possible answers: `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`

As for why you can't tell `rand()` the max value you want directly... Well that's just not how the function was coded. You are of course free to write your own with a max value parameter.

Answer (score 1):

`rand() % 11` returns a random number between 0 and 10; `rand() % 10 + 1` returns a number between 0 and 9, and then adds 1, resulting in a number between 1 and 10.

`rand()` can't take a max value in part because there's no guarantee as to what the max number `rand()` returns will be - it [varies based on implementation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_rand.htm) (but is always guaranteed to be at least 32767). You can find the exact value in the constant `RAND_MAX`.